# Can't run AndroidDriver on emulated android device in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, android-emulator, webdriver, appium

I'm trying to run an Android driver within Selenium but am running into an odd error I don't know how to fix. I have a running Appium Server and also a running Android Emulator (through Android Studio) that shows up as "emulator-5554" when I run "adb devices" in the command line. However, when I try to actually start the emulator and open "Chrome" within the android emulator, I get the following exception:

```
A new session could not be created. (Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (Original error: unknown error: Device emulator-5554 is not online
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845 (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d8c96a94682a),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64))) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 4.32 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
```

Here is my code:

```
public void useAndroid(){
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", "Chrome");

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
        WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(url, capabilities);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    open("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Any ideas why this exception could be happening? I've done a lot of searching around and I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

From the logs, it seems emulator (emulator-5554) was in offline mode during test execution. Add capabilities for emulator name and wait for emulator to go to online state before test execution.

Also, Instead of open use get api -

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```